# File not incrementing by 1 after running the program again

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program that when I run creates a new file, and creates a new file while incrementing the end by 1 every time the program runs. At least that's what it should do.

```
import os 

statment='testing file\n###########'
f=1
filename='TEST%s.in'
while os.path.exists(filename % f):
    f+=1
with open('Model' + filename % f, 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(statment)
    outfile.writelines('\n')
    outfile.writelines('test')
```

It'll create the first file as TEST1.in, but it won't create the second file that should be named TEST2.in after I run the program again.

Should I not be using a while loop for this or is there something I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the question! It looks like there is some code in your post that is not relevant the question. Could you reduce it down, so that we can run the code ourself?

Comment: @Quelklef Okay, it's cut down

Comment: if you run the program again `f` should be again intialized with`1`. so you will not get 2

Comment: You check for the existence of files with names `filename % f`, but then create a file with the name `'Model' + filename % f`. Why would you expect the check to matter? You never actually created `TEST1.in` this way, but instead `ModelTEST1.in`.

Comment: Thank you all for making me feel really stupid haha. Self-teaching is a struggle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the path you're testing for is different than the one you're opening/creating

`os.path.exists(filename % f)` vs `open('Model' + filename % f, 'w')`

So it never finds an existing file and always opens with `1`

Comment: Thank you all for making me feel really stupid haha. Self-teaching is a struggle.

Answer (score 0):

Would add to [Michael Speer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152043/michael-speer)'s answer the act of assigning a variable holding the path so you don't duplicate building the path:

```
while os.path.exists( path := 'Model' + ( filename % f ) ):
    f += 1
    
with     open(path, 'w') as outfile:
```

This makes it obvious that the same path is being used in both places.

See [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) for Assignment Expressions if you do not know `:=`.